# mod rewrite css issue

Tags: php, css, mod-rewrite

I am new to using mod rewrite but all my css and images go wrong if im not in the root directory

i have this as my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test2/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NS]
```

and

this is my link to my css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

can anyone help?

cheers matt

Comment: Remove the last slash on `RewriteBase /test2/`. And also, are you **sure** your css file exists?

Comment: the css works if im at the root

Comment: @MattMoseley Worth mentioning. Have you tried `../style.css`? Try as many `../` as it will take to reach the folder it's in. Or try a straight `http://www.yoursite.com/foldername/where/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//mysite.com/style.css" />
```

otherwise your browser searches for the stylesheet in the same path youre currently visiting. So if you visit /news/article/1 your browser requests /news/article/1/style.css but it obviously cant find it there.

Comment: and what about /test2/style.css (assuming that is your directory)